# Hyperledger Fabric Orderer generating some logs when using Kafka consensus

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric

I am running hyperledger fabric 1.2 with kafka consensus . I am trying to setup my network and channel over AWS . But in the process of network bootstrap I am getting some logs on each orderer (In my case 2).

`2018-12-27 06:21:53.905 UTC [grpc] Println -> DEBU 0e3 grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport:  connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to receive the preface from client: EOF"`

While everything is working fine for me like instantiation, invocation and all  .

One more thing when I instantiate the chaincode. logs seems to be ok.

`2018-12-27 06:27:34.570 UTC [fsblkstorage] nextBlockBytesAndPlacementInfo -> DEBU 2b4 blockbytes [5223] read from file [0]
2018-12-27 06:27:34.570 UTC [common/deliver] deliverBlocks -> DEBU 2b5 [channel: testchannel] Delivering block for (0xc420664d00) for 52.54.151.0:47542
2018-12-27 06:27:34.570 UTC [fsblkstorage] waitForBlock -> DEBU 2b6 Going to wait for newer blocks. maxAvailaBlockNumber=[2], waitForBlockNum=[3]`

So anyone have any idea about the situation that what is going on there.Should i need to be worry about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: logs seems to be related to health check of server

Comment: have you setup anchor peers for each peer organization yet?

Comment: yes i setup anchor peers